# Why the BoxFit enum not working as expected?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to cover the entire canvas with an image. For this, I am using `BoxFit.cover` enum. But it is not working.

Code :

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: 
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/choco.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Output Screenshot :**

[image: Output Screenshot]
**Why is it not covering the entire screen? None of the `BoxFit` enum values are working. Please explain in detail. Thank you.**

Answer (score 17):

`Stack` also has a `fit` property, so set fit to `StackFit.expand`.

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  ...
```

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack/fit.html

If you don't have a parent widget for you `Image` try using the `height` and `width` property.

```
   Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/choco.jpg"),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want to know why the given code doesn't work. Forget about `Stack` widget, it also doesn't work if I use `Image` directly without `Stack`.

Comment: because that widget needs a parent to set the constraints and fill the entire screen :)

Comment: Solved my problem as a Stack was my Image's ancestor. I recommend others checking out constraints of the parents if otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Images are not knowing the width to cover.
Wrap your image with a `Container()` and set width: `double.infinity,` for it.

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/choco.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
           ),
),
```